# When is it necessary to enable SSL on MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I read on the Microsoft website that the SmtpClient was obsolete and they recommended using the MailKit for it's replacement.

I'm in the process of writing an application to make use of the MailKit.

This is what I have so far:

```
    // *************** SEND EMAIL *******************
    using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
    {
      //accept all SSL certificates
      client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

      client.Connect(emailSettings.SmtpServer, emailSettings.SmtpPort, emailSettings.IsSslEnabled);

      if (emailSettings.IsAuthenticationRequired)
      {
        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate(emailSettings.SmtpUsername, emailSettings.SmtpPassword);
      }

      // timeout = 20 seconds
      client.Timeout = 20000;

      client.Send(message);
      client.Disconnect(true);
    }
```

When I set this part:

```
client.Connect(emailSettings.SmtpServer, emailSettings.SmtpPort, emailSettings.IsSslEnabled);
```

the last parameter is `bool useSSL`, which I set to true. My email server is hosted by Rackspace so I know that it uses SSL.  When I set this option to true, it fails to send but if I set this option to false, it sends fine.

Shouldn't this line catch the certificate type:

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

If so, why wouldn't `useSSL` on the connect not work? Do I need to set the `useSSL` to false? I'm confused on how the `useSSL` works when I have the line above.

Comment: "Shouldn't this line catch the certificate type" Yes, unless it never gets this far.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Mail protocols (SMTP, IMAP, and POP3) all have 2 different ways of doing SSL.

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient only implemented support for the `STARTTLS` way of doing SSL whereas MailKit does both.

When you specify `useSsl` as `true` in MailKit's `Connect` method, it assumes that you meant to use an SSL-wrapped connection (which is different from `STARTTLS`).

To make this less confusing, MailKit has a `Connect` method that takes a `SecureSocketOptions` argument instead of a `bool`.

The options are as follows:

- `None`: Don't use any form of SSL (or TLS).
- `Auto`: Automatically decides which type of SSL mode to use based on the specified port. Note: This only works reliable when the port is a standard defined port (e.g. 25, 587 or 465 for SMTP).
- `SslOnConnect`: This specifies that MailKit should connect via an SSL-wrapped connection.
- `StartTls`: Use the `STARTTLS` method for SSL/TLS encryption. If the server doesn't support the `STARTTLS` command, abort the connection.
- `StartTlsWhenAvailable`: Use the `STARTTLS` method for SSL/TLS encryption if the server supports it, otherwise continue using an unencrypted channel.

Since you are using SMTP, you might find this useful:

Port `25` was the original port used for SMTP and it originally only supported unencrypted communications.

Later, administrators and users demanded SSL encryption so admins and mail clients started supporting SSL-wrapped connections on port `465` because this was very easy to do for admins (no server software needed to be upgraded and clients that didn't support SSL-wrapped connections could continue connecting on port `25`).

After a few years of this, mail protocol authors introduced the `STARTTLS` command extension for IMAP, SMTP and POP3 (well, for POP3, the command is `STLS` but it is otherwise the same thing) that clients could optionally use if they supported it. This extension only made sense on the original (non-SSL-wrapped) ports.

These days `STARTTLS` is the preferred method for encrypting communications between a client and a mail server, but SSL-wrapped ports are still in wide use as well.

MailKit treats port `587` the same as it treats `25`. In other words, it treats port `25` and `587` as a plain-text connection port but will switch to SSL/TLS if requested to do so via `STARTTLS`.